# Create a page in personal site for all users in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, application-pages

I want to create a page with custom webpart which will be accessible to all users, I can create it in main site but the page is accessible from url `http://myspsite.com/pages/mynewpage.aspx`. Although this page is accessible to all the users which have access to SharePoint site, I want to create this page in MySite/Personal Site as follows:
`http://myspsite.com/sites/My/SitePages/mynewpage.aspx`

Can anyone help or share how to create page at above location which will be accessible to all users across site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can grant permissions to users to access this page though right click the page file->share with->advanced->stop Inheriting Permissions->Grant permissions.

Besides, since mysite is a site collection different from SharePoint team site, there is no OOB method to grant permissions to users who have access to SharePoint team site. As an alternative, I suggest you using PowerShell script to get the users who have access to SharePoint site, and grant permissions to these users to the new created page.